# Faster input and output

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i,x,max=0;
    cin>>x;
    int a[x];
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        if(max<a[i]){
            max=a[i];}                 
        }
        int b[max+1];
        for(i=0;i<max+1;i++){
            b[i]=-1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
            if(b[a[i]]==-1){
            b[a[i]]=1;
        }
        else{
            b[a[i]]++;
        }
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<=max){
        while(b[i]>0&&b[i]!=-1){
            cout<<i<<endl;
            b[i]--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Guys I tried indexing method for sorting and codechef shows tle .. complexity of this problem is not o(n) but closer to it ... the question has a time limit of 5 sec and source limit is 50000 bytes..

Any help on how to improve the performance either by faster i/o or code computations ...

Comment: What do you mean by closer to it?

Comment: i mean under worst case scenario it has a  complexity closer o(n)(due to 2 while loops)

Comment: What does this code do? What are the requirements? What data do you test it with?

Comment: sorting .....i mentioned it... all cases x varies from 0 to 10^6 ... and any input for array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty certain your code is problematic because you are using `cout << x << endl;` in a loop that will print a huge number of lines.

I will be back with "difference" in a few minutes.

Edit: Not sure I can make much of a difference either way. Obviously, depending on compiler, it may vary greatly, but with my g++ -O2 and 100000 input numbers, it takes 0.16 - 0.18s to use `endl;` and 0.06 - 0.07s to use `'\n'` for the output.

Using `printf` isn't faster than `cout`, but `scanf` is a little faster than `cin` (0.04s +/- 0.05).

However, that is really related to `sync_with_stdio`. If we use `cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` then the results are the same for `scanf` and `cin`.

All measurements are made with a file as input and a file as output - it takes much longer to write to the shell, but that's because it's scrolling 100k lines of text past me.

(Your program will crash with eithr "large" inputs or with large number of inputs - if `max` is greater than about 1 million, the code will crash due to out of stack - on many systems, that may happen for lower values too)

Comment: y would it crash for lower values??codechef restricted the limit to 10^6

Comment: It would crash at various counts, depending on the size of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid **cin** and **cout**, and use the C IO functions **scanf** and **printf** instead. You'll find they can be up to 5x faster than the slow c++ functions.

Comment: If you plan to use codechef more, you might want to even make a readInt() function that uses getc() to extract numbers from stdin. It can be very helpful when there are millions of input to extract. Doing this can be up to 10x faster than cin and cout. cin and cout weren't designed with the thought in mind that they would be called that many times. :P

Comment: I would point out that the above answer isn't entirely accurate. The problem is mainly with flushing `cout` on every `endl`